# Dapper insert or Update?

Tags: dapper

I haven't started using Dapper just yet but just stumbled across it today as I was researching about bulk insert/updates. Currently I'm using EF6 but I would like to look at using Dapper in the future of my bulk stuff. For this app there could be ~15k records but I have other apps that could be ~100k records.

I'm trying to research a way that I could convert the following EF code into Dapper. All it does is reads in a record from a file, look to see if that employee exists in the DB, if so it updates the properties with the values from the file and if not it creates a new object with the values from the file.

I couldn't find any examples when I was looking around. All I could find was how to do a simple insert or an update. I didn't really find a good examples of bulk insert/update. It's very possible I'm just not understanding how to use Dapper just yet.

How would I do this with Dapper?

```
int count = 1;
using (ctx = new DataContext())
{
    ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;      
    ctx.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

    while ((record = srFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int employeeId = int.Parse(record.Substring(2, 8));

        bio_employee employee = ctx.bio_employee.FirstOrDefault(e => e.emp_id == employeeId);

        if (employee != null)
        {
            SetEmployeeData(employee, record);

            ctx.Entry(employee).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            employee = new bio_employee();
            employee.emp_id = employeeId;

            SetEmployeeData(employee, record);

            ctx.bio_employee.Add(employee);
        }


        if (count % batchSize == 0)
        {
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            ctx.Dispose();
            ctx = new DataContext();
        }

        count++;
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();      //save any remaining
}
```

Comment: I think there's two different things here: a) how to do an upsert in TSQL; b) how to call TSQL from dapper. The latter is very easy - the tricky bit is the former, but that isn't a dapper concern, it is a TSQL one. Try googling "upsert sql server"

Answer (score 11):

Dapper provides multiple methods to query data but none to perform saving operations other than using a command like you normally do without an ORM.

A lot of third party libraries cover however this scenario for Dapper:

- [Dapper Plus](http://dapper-plus.net/)
- [Dapper Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib)
- [Dapper Extensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions)
- [Dapper FastCRUD](https://github.com/MoonStorm/Dapper.FastCRUD)
- [Dapper SimpleCRUD](https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Dapper Plus](http://dapper-plus.net/)

Dapper Plus is by far the fastest library by providing: BulkInsert, BulkDelete, BulkUpdate, and BulkMerge operations. It can easily support scenarios with millions of records.

```
// CONFIGURE & MAP entity
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Employee>()
                 .Table("Employee")
                 .Identity(x => x.EmployeeID);

// SAVE entity
connection.BulkMerge(employeeList);
```

**EDIT**: Answer subquestion

> Is the .BulkMerge in your DapperPlus doing an Upsert

Yes, BulkMerge is an upsert operation.

You can also specify more than one mapping for the same entity by using a mapping key.

```
// Using key from database (x => x.EmployeeID)
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Employee>()
                 .Table("Employee");

connection.BulkInsert(employees);

// Using custom key
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Employee>("customKey")
                 .Table("Employee")
                 .Key(x => x.Code);

connection.BulkInsert("customKey", employees);
```

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look. Is the .BulkMerge in your DapperPlus doing an Upsert? So I could just pass a list of employees and it will either update them or insert new ones?

Comment: my current project happens to be in SQL but the majority of stuff at my work is Oracle. Your site shows that Oracle is coming soon. Any ETA on that part of it?

Comment: I hope to be able to support it finally before the end of this month. We completed all necessary research to optimize query a few weeks ago.

Comment: Probably [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib) should also be on the list?

Comment: Thank @Uwm, added ;)

Comment: Dapper.Contrib seems to be the "official" set of extensions provided by the same team that created Dapper.

Comment: One question: do we have to use the `SaveChanges()` method after the insert or update?

Comment: No @Rias, BulkInsert is an immediate operation (which means it's executed when you call it like SaveChanges().

Comment: please note that Dapper plus is not free

Comment: Thanks for listing all the libraries here. Was easy to test and compare them to perform insert operation of C# entity data for a MySQL table having no primary/identity key and all columns were string! Found another solution to create insert statement dynamically where those columns had space in their name also! Found a work around from one of the answers of SO question 21857368.