# How to check if a record with composite key already exists in mysql database before inserting it using Dapper in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

Supplier and Invoice are composite keys in a table which consists of 9 fields

Comment: Try to SELECT an item with those fields?

Comment: How exactly using Dapper, i understand using Entity Framework where you do something like.   return db.table.Find(key1, key2) != null;

Comment: @Ronald Do you have experience using a `WHERE` clause with Dapper?

Comment: Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply perform an SELECT query first then insert or you can do so in a single trip as shown below (SQL Server).  You can use one of the recommended Dapper extensions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127880/dapper-insert-or-update)

```
string cmd = @"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE SupplierId=@SupplierId AND InvoiceId=@InvoiceId)
                    BEGIN 
                        INSERT INTO Table1(SupplierId, InvoiceId) VALUES(@SupplierId, @InvoiceId)
                    END";

using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=true"))
{
    dbConn.Execute(cmd, new { SupplierId = 1, InvoiceId = 2 });
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

**UPDATE**
For MySQL, you can write something like

`INSERT INTO Table1 (SupplierId, InvoiceId) VALUES(@SupplierId, @InvoiceId)  ON DUPLICATE KEY SupplierId=SupplierId`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html